# NCURSES and Linux Input Device

Tags: c++, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, ncurses

I wrote a *getSample(devicePath)* function that reads raw input events from keyboard, however after running this function, *ncurses* doesn't display anything.

includes

```
#include <linux/input.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <ncurses.h>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
```

getSample

```
const int KEY_PRESSED = 1;
const int KEY_RELEASED = 0;

std::vector<input_event> getSample(std::string devicePath) {
  std::vector<input_event> events;
  int fileDescriptor = open(devicePath.c_str(), O_RDONLY);
  while (true) {
    struct input_event event;
    read(fileDescriptor, &event, sizeof(struct input_event));
    if (event.type == EV_KEY)
      if (event.value == KEY_PRESSED || event.value == KEY_RELEASED) {
        if (event.code == 28 && event.value == KEY_PRESSED)
          break;
        events.push_back(event);
      }
  }
  close(fileDescriptor);
  return events;
}
```

main

```
int main() {
  std::string devicePath = "/dev/input/by-id/"
                           "usb-Microsft_Microsoft_Wireless_Desktop_Receiver_3."
                           "1-event-kbd";
  std::vector<input_event> sample = getSample(devicePath);
  initscr();
  printw("Hello World!");
  refresh();
  getch();
  endwin();
  return 0;
}
```

Is there a way to fix it?

---

**Tip**

Function *getSample* works correctly, because when I replace *ncurses* code with simple *printf()*, everything works fine

```
int main() {
  std::string devicePath = "/dev/input/by-id/"
                           "usb-Microsft_Microsoft_Wireless_Desktop_Receiver_3."
                           "1-event-kbd";
  std::vector<input_event> sample = getSample(devicePath);

  for (unsigned int i = 0; i < sample.size(); i++)
    printf("%d | %3d | %ld.%06ld\n", sample[i].value, sample[i].code,
           (long)sample[i].time.tv_sec, (long)sample[i].time.tv_usec);

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Without the #include's, your question requires work from people who might answer it.

Comment: Ok, I added includes

Comment: Where are `KEY_PRESSED` and `KEY_RELEASED` defined?

Comment: The input devices are normally accessible by `root` only; your sample program does not check for failure to open the device.  Assuming you ran this as `root` however - is the input device for instance the same as your regular keyboard (so that it might interfere with the standard input)?

Comment: Yes, I run it as root. Function _getSample()_ works correctly, because when I simply `prinf()` _vector sample_ elements I see them on the screen

Comment: Then (assuming it exits nicely from the loop), it sounds as if it interferes with standard input.  That break right after a key-pressed event might be part of the problem, e.g., not waiting for the key-released event.  But if that is really a different device from your terminal, I don't see why it would conflict.  (If I had a good way to test the program, I would trace ncurses to see where it is hung - but even with just gdb you could attach to the process and see where it is, when it seems to be doing nothing).

Comment: You were right that problem lies with inputes. They are being buffered and processed right after breaking the loop. This makes getch() function being executed instantly, so I don't see anything on the screen. Do you know how I can clear buffer? Thanks is advance

Comment: If you were expecting the events to be transferred to use by `getch`, I would have expected the `initscr` call first (before `getSample`), and a loop calling `ungetch` to copy the data into ncurses' input `FIFO` (which holds up to 135 characters).